# How to ignore primary auto-incremented column in Library (ifsnop / mysqldump-php)

Tags: php, mysql

I want to use library (ifsnop/mysqldump-php) for daily backup of one single table from multiple location and want to upload all backup on server, Only problem I am facing it is  having error - duplicate of Primary key ID (1st column) Auto increment, please help

[Library Link Click Here](https://github.com/ifsnop/mysqldump-php)

Below is the code I am using, please guide me how I can ignore Autoincrement column which is 1st column and I want to use this library as I feel feasible to my requirement

Reason I am using this library I have xampp in my local computer and with button click I can take backup in a specific folder

```
include 'Mysqldump.php';

use Ifsnop\Mysqldump as IMysqldump;
//include_once (dirname(__FILE__) . '/mysqldump/Mysqldump.php');
$date = date('Ymd');
$dumpSettings = array(
    'include-tables' => array('average_cost_calculation'),
    'compress' => IMysqldump\Mysqldump::NONE,
    'no-data' => false,
    'add-drop-table' => false,
    'single-transaction' => false,
    'lock-tables' => true,
    'add-locks' => true,
    'if-not-exists' => true,
//    'disable-foreign-keys-check' => false,
    'extended-insert' => true,
    'complete-insert' => true,
    'insert-ignore' => false,
    'disable-keys' => false,
  //  'reset-auto-increment' => true,
    'skip-triggers' => false,
    'add-drop-trigger' => true,
    'databases' => false,
    'add-drop-database' => false,
    'where' => 'store_code ="1000" ',
    'hex-blob' => true
    );

$dump = new IMysqldump\Mysqldump("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=naeem_pos_database", "root", "", $dumpSettings);
$dump->start("uploads/backup${date}.sql");
```

Comment: PHP should never be responsible for actually running database backups, because PHP is _designed_ to die if it runs for too long. Write a regular MySQL backup job (e.g. a bash script) and at best make PHP initiate that, but I have no idea why you'd do that if this is a daily backup: make it a cron job so that it runs all on its own every day at a specific time.

Comment: This one i am using to make a backup in local computer than it is uploaded to main server . Actual I found solution to this , within the library guideline